# BeginAcceptSocket with null as a state object - issue?

Tags: c#, networking, asynchronous

I have been given a code that also involves an asynchronous socketing which I am begginer at. I do not know why the object state as a second parameter of BeginAccept socket is null and to be honest, I did not get the use of this parameter from MSDN. And also, why the BeginAccept is being called again from the callback method?

```
public void Start()
        {

                this.mTcpListener.Start();
                this.mTcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket(this.AcceptClient, null);
        }

 protected void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            if (this.mTcpListener != null)
            {
                System.Net.Sockets.Socket s = this.mTcpListener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);
                Client c = new Client(this, s, this.GetFreePlayerID());

                ..some code for adding the client instance to collection....                  
                this.mTcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket(this.AcceptClient, null);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from fsimonazzi, I assume that this code is part of a server which is meant to hold many incoming connections.

BeginAccept is used to start the accept process on a socket.

In AcceptClient it then finishes the AcceptConnection async process with EndAcceptSocket.

At this point the program is no longer listening for new connections/sockets. In order to do that, it again starts an async BeginAcceptSocket process.

Answer (score 0):

That parameter is purely used by the calling code. It gets paced back to your callback, and you can used it to identify a call. Using null is perfectly valid.

Here's more information about the Asynchronous Programming Model http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx.

The second additional parameter is a user-defined object. This object can be used to pass application-specific state information to the method invoked when the asynchronous operation completes.